# Install Mysql 5.6.4 or greater on web server with on CentOS / openSUSE with Plesk 10

Tags: mysql, centos, plesk, opensuse

I need to install MySQL 5.6.4 or greater on my web server because I'm using the full text innodb feature. I'm trying to move my local installation (WAMP server) to my dedicated server and I'm not able to find a version greater than 5.5 in the repository my system is configured to use (I'm not a Linux expert at all).

I can install either CentOS 6 with Parallels Plesk Panel 10 (64-bit) or openSUSE 11.4 with Parallels Plesk Panel 10 (64-bit) on my server.

Can anyone provide a guide to install MySQL 5.6.4?

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is:

to avoid possible issues with Plesk installed with MySQL 5.6.4 on the same server it would be better to install MySQL 5.6.4 to separate server and then register it in your Plesk instance as external DB server.

Such approach will protect you from possible incompatibilities of Plesk with new MySQL version and you will be able to use new version of MySQL for your application.

I believe that to install MySQL you can download source files from the vendor side and compile it to install to a system or find it in some of 3rd party repo.